# Slow mysql query (using IN)

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT Description, Temp1, Temp2, SensorData.DateAndTime
FROM SensorData 
     INNER Join Sensors on Sensors.ChipId=SensorData.RockID 
WHERE SensorData.Id in (Select max(Id) LastRecord 
                        From SensorData  
                        Group by RockId)
ORDER BY DhtTemp;
```

It takes 3 seconds. If I remove the inner select query and replace it with the results from the query it takes .1 seconds. If I run the inner query alone it takes .1 seconds. If I remove the Join to Sensors it runs in .5 seconds (which would be fine.) Any advice? I have Indexes on The Id columns which are INT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ChipId` in `Sensors` table is used in join condition and `RockId` in inner select query is `group by` column name, have you tried to index this columns?

in Addition try this query:

```
 SELECT Description, Temp1, Temp2, myData.DateAndTime
 FROM
     (SELECT *,max(id) as mymax FROM SensorData 
      Group by RockId
      Order by id desc
      ) as myData
 INNER Join Sensors on Sensors.ChipId= myData.RockID 
 WHERE SensorData.Id = mydata.mymax 
 ORDER BY DhtTemp;
```

Comment: I like it. I added a where clause to the inner query to reduce the number of rows returned and it is blazing fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most `where in (select ...)` queries can be rewritten (often automatically by the optimiser, but not always) as joins; try this:

```
select Description, Temp1, Temp2, a.DateAndTime
from SensorData a
left join SensorData b on b.RockId = a.RockId
    and b.ID > a.ID
join Sensors on Sensors.ChipId = a.RockID 
where b.ID is null
order by DhtTemp
```

In English, this means "only return SensorData rows that don't have a higher ID`.

Make sure you have in index on `RockId`.

Comment: Yes, a valid query, but hardly quick!